# unable to use fmriprep-docker

Tags: sudo, docker, pip

Here's the command I used for the data:

```
sudo fmriprep-docker -i poldracklab/fmriprep:20.2.0 -u 131231231167:12123123231405 /data/asdf/fmri_data/sourcedata /data/asdf/fmri_data/derivatives participant --fs-no-reconall -w /data/asdf/fmri_data/scratch --output-spaces MNI152NLin2009cAsym:res-2 --participant_label asdf1 asdf2 asdf3
```

and here's the error I get:

```
sudo: fmriprep-docker: command not found
```

However, **fmriprep-docker** is installed on the server. Am I on the sudoers list for fmriprep?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

do this:

```
pip3 install --user --upgrade fmriprep-docker
echo 'export PATH=$PATH:~/.local/bin' >> ~/.bash_profile
source ~/.bash_profile
```

the first command installs fmriprep docker into `~/.local/bin`

the rest makes sure the shell looks there for programs to run